# Symfony 4 - Why does security voter redirect me to the login page when it returns false?

Tags: symfony, security

there is something I don't understand in Symfony 4.

I have a custom voter in which I check if I have a property that is true or false:

```
/**
 * Vérifie si les essais gratuits sont activés
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function isFreeTrialEnabled(): bool
{
    $stripeParameters = $this->manager->getRepository(StripeParameters::class)->findOneBy([]);
    return $stripeParameters->getFreeTrial();
}
```

In my controller, I've :

```
/**
 * @Route("/trial", name="account_trial")
 * @Security("is_granted(constant('\\App\\Security\\Stripe\\Voter\\StripeClientVoter::IS_FREE_TRIAL_ENABLED'))")
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @param UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder
 * @param SubscriptionHelper $subscriptionHelper
 * @param EntityManagerInterface $manager
 * @param StripeClient $stripeClient
 * @return Response
 */
public function trialAction(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder, SubscriptionHelper $subscriptionHelper , EntityManagerInterface $manager, StripeClient $stripeClient)
{ //... }
```

So if the vote returns true, it lets me in. If it returns false, it should put an access denied exception.

However, when it returns false to me, it brings me back directly to the login page

Comment: Whenever authentication fails the user is redirected to the login form if you are using login form authentication. Check [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login.html#redirecting-after-failure) if you want to affect this behavior. But what would you want to happen on authentication failure?

Comment: Actually this should only happen if the user is currently not logged in

Comment: Yes, my voter has to work for anonymous users (and connected users too). I would like that if it's an anonymous or connected user, it happen an error.

Comment: I don’t see where do you call your voter ? I just see a constant in the `is_granted section` but I think you should pass a role https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html#how-symfony-uses-voters if you understand French you can take a look to this video https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=WLzNBYDN7Ck

Comment: Smaïne je vois que tu es français aussi. Du coup pour t'expliquer, j'ai une page qui peut être accessible par soit un user connecté (et dans le cas où il remplit certaines conditions), soit par un utilisateur anonyme. Et en plus de tout ça, il faut qu'une certaine valeur issue des paramètres administrateurs soit activée. Donc dans le cas où la valeur n'est pas activée, la page (qui existe en vrai puisqu'elle est codée) doit retourner une erreur pour faire comme si elle n'était pas accessible

Comment: My goal is to be able to include anonymous and connected users in the vote. If the user is logged in, then do the verification A. If he is anonymous, do the verification B. And in both cases, do the verification C. If one of the conditions returns "false", then, prohibit access. This is what I want

Comment: But the main problem I encounter when I create a vote is to be able to manage the case where it is anonymous. When it returns false, then necessarily, I am redirected to the login page. By cons if I am connected, the conditions work